# substitute does not work as expected

Tags: r

According to the document

> Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse tree as follows: If it is not a bound symbol in env, it is unchanged. If it is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to a function or explicitly created using delayedAssign(), the expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol. If it is an ordinary variable, its value is substituted, unless env is .GlobalEnv in which case the symbol is left unchanged.

So I did some experiments

```
a = 10

# first
f1 = function(x){
  substitute(x)
  }
f1(a)
# [1] a


# second
f1 = function(x){
  x
  substitute(x)
  }
f1(a)
# [1] a

# third
f1 = function(x){
  force(x)
  substitute(x)
  }
f1(a)
# [1] a

# fourth
f1 = function(x){
  x = x
  substitute(x)
  }
f1(a)
# [1] 10
```

In the second and third experiments, I supposed that x was not a promise anymore,  so `substitute` should return `10` instead of `a`. But it still returned `a`. Why?

Comment: `x` and `force(x)` were not assigned in the second and third cases. As such, `substitute(x)` is returned in both cases as the original value of `x`, i.e. `a`

Comment: If `force(x)` is assigned, e.g. `f1 <-function(x){tmp <- force(x); substitute(tmp)}` then `f1(a)` will return the value `10`

Comment: From the language definition: "Until that argument is accessed there is no value associated with the promise. When the argument is accessed, the stored expression is evaluated in the stored environment, and the result is returned. The result is also saved by the promise. The substitute function will extract the content of the expression slot. This allows the programmer to access either the value or the expression associated with the promise." A promise stays a promise even if its expression has been evaluated.

Comment: @AdamQuek I agree that this is related to whether `x` is assigned or not. But how does `substitute` detect that  `x` is assigned? If you use `ls.str(environment())` you can see that `x` is already bound to `10`.

Comment: @Roland I see. So unless promise `x` is overrided with a local variable 'x', it stays a promise regardless of whether it is evaluated or not.

Comment: That's how I understand the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects):

> Until that argument is accessed there is no value associated with the
>   promise. When the argument is accessed, the stored expression is
>   evaluated in the stored environment, and the result is returned. The
>   result is also saved by the promise. The substitute function will
>   extract the content of the expression slot. This allows the programmer
>   to access either the value or the expression associated with the
>   promise.

A promise stays a promise even if its expression has been evaluated. You can see what happens with the pryr package:

```
library(pryr)
f=function(x){
  print(promise_info(x))
  force(x)
  promise_info(x)
}

a <- 10
f(a)

#$code
#a
#
#$env
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#
#$evaled
#[1] FALSE
#
#$value
#NULL
############################
#$code
#a
#
#$env
#NULL
#
#$evaled
#[1] TRUE
#
#$value
#[1] 10
```

Obviously, assigning a new value to the symbol replaces the promise with that value. That's what happens in your last function.